# Write string and variables to file in python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write a line to text file in python with below code but its giving me an error

```
logfile.write('Total Matched lines : ', len(matched_lines))
```

i know we cannot give 2 arguments for .write but whats the right way to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn it into *one* argument, such as with the newish format strings:

```
logfile.write(f'Total Matched lines : {len(matched_lines)}\n')
```

Or, if you're running a version before where this facility was added (3.6, I think), one of the following:

```
logfile.write('Total Matched lines : {}\n'.format(len(matched_lines)))
logfile.write('Total Matched lines : ' + str(len(matched_lines)) + '\n')
```

> Aside: I've added a newline since you're writing to a log file (most likely textual) and `write` does not do so. Feel free to ignore the `\n` if you've made the decision to *not* write it on an individual line.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
logfile.write('Total Matched lines : {}'.format(len(matched_lines)))
```

or:

```
logfile.write('Total Matched lines : %d' % len(matched_lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

```
logfile.write('Total matches lines: ' + str(len(matched_lines)))
```

Or:

```
logfile.write('Total matches lines: {}'.format(len(matched_lines)))
```